# Symfony2 access all form errors without form_bubbling

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to know if it is possible to access all of my form's errors without using form_bubbling since it gives the error to the parent and individual objects loose their error...I need both the form to know globally if there are errors to display a global "please fix your errors" message and the individual elements to know if they contain errors because I will add an error CSS class to invalid form inputs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok after speaking to people in Symfony's IRC channel, there exists two ways to do this:

 1. form.has('errors') for a simple boolean stating weither or not the form contains errors.
 2. form.vars.errors|length for the exact number of errors contained in the form.

Problem solved. All of this can be used without using error_bubbling.

Comment: Please post your edit as an answer and accept it, so that people having the same issue can see it is solved :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After speaking to people in Symfony's IRC channel, there exists two ways to do this in a Twig template:

1. `form.has('errors')` for a boolean stating whether or not the form contains errors.
2. `form.vars.errors|length` for the number of errors contained in the form.

Problem solved. All of this can be used without using error_bubbling.

Comment: If `form_bubbling == false`, your solution doesn't work, as `form.get('errors')` return an empty array, even if some fields have errors.

Comment: Does not work if error_bubbling is false, I found that @ClementHerreman solution worked well with a minor tweak.

Comment: I don't see any way listed here to see the actual errors, just the number of errors or whether there are errors.

Comment: It doesn't work. One still has to set form_bubbling = true on each and every field.

Comment: ```Method "has" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist```

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient way I found to get the numbers of errors of a form, regarless its `form_bubbling` is `true`or `false` is to add, in the controller, some variable indicating it :

```
return $this->render('Acme:Contrats:index.html.twig', array(
    'myform' => $form->createView(),
    'myformHasErrors' => !$form->isValid(),
));
```

If anyone find another one, please comment/answer this.

Comment: This works great, but the form must be bound, when its not, this tweak is also possible: 'myFormHasErrors' => $form->isBound() ? !$form->isValid(): false,

Comment: @StevenRosato IT seems rather odd to validate a form, when there's no data to validate against, ie it is not bound. But yes, your suggestion works :)